# Need to import a single GnuPG public key into the pubring

Tags: gnupg

This is for a Python based GnuPg user friendly front-end program.
Have been trying to find the command for importing just one public key, rather than all of them.
This imorts all keys in the file
gpg --import Some_pub_keys.txt

I tried this:
gpg --import 6CA398EA Some_pub_keys.txt

To only import this key 6CA398EA, but it did not work.

Is there a command for importing just a single key?

Answer (score 7):

What you want is this:

```
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring myapp_keyring.gpg --import a_key.asc
```

The first flag tells GPG not to use your default keyrings, the second tells it to use the file myapp_keyring.gpg as the keyring file and the last is the import command.  Note, the alternate keyring file MUST be of the GPG or OpenPGP format, so it will generally use either the .gpg or .pgp extension and not .txt (or anything else).

Comment: How would this work if import is not from a keyring, but from an ASCII file to which a few public keys were exported?

Comment: The same way. It doesn't matter how many keys are in the .asc file, they'll all be imported to the keyring specified. Specifying a keyring file that does not (yet) exist will create the keyring.

Comment: Pls forgive me, but I still don't understand. **I don't want to import all the keys in the _.asc_ file, I only want to import the specified keys.**

Will the command that you showed above allow me to chose which keys to import?
How will I tell gpg which key to import?
Can I specify the email address, or keyID?

Comment: Oh, I see. No, importing is an all or nothing thing, but you can import the .asc file to an alternate keyring file and then delete the keys you don't want in there. This would do it: gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring myapp_keyring.gpg --delete-keys 0xDEADBEEF

Comment: Also, if that takes too long (e.g. if there are dozens of unwanted keys and you only want one) you can import them all into a temporary file and then export the key you want: gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /tmp/temp.gpg --import bunch_of_keys.asc ; gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /tmp/temp.gpg -o myapp_keyring.gpg --export 0xDEADBEEF ; rm -f /tmp/temp.gpg

Comment: OK, now I understand.
GPG does not not have a command for importing selected keys. It is all or nothing.
Too bad, I'd wish they had.
Anyway, thanks so much for your explanation.

Comment: It's only because the ASCII armoured files can't be used like keyrings, whereas keys exported in the .gpg (or .pgp for commercial implementations of OpenPGP) are handled the same way as keyrings.

Comment: Sorry, now I am confused again. I thought you were saying that even from keyrings I can only import all keys at once, but not only selected keys.
There are commands for exporting only selected keys to a keyring, but as far as I am aware no corresponding command for importing.

Comment: Correct, the --import option can only import everything in the file specified, the --export option allows specifying any number of keys. This is because exporting is working from your keyring, either the default one or a specified one, and thus GPG is able to access the keys individually. Whereas importing is accessing a file which is not (yet) a part of your keyring. That said, if the key file is a .gpg file instead of a .asc file then it can be loaded as a keyring using the examples I gave previously.